# Angular router events.url not loading on first time

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

Does anyone have any ideas on how to get the router events to fire the first time the page/component is loaded?

I have the below in the main parent component of my app, it works ok,

however, when the app loads for the first time it returns nothing,

I tried using the startWith rxjs operator to put something into the event.url when the page loads,

But what this does is give an incorrect url, if you are starting in a different place...

```
prog(): void {
  this.subs = this.router.events
    .pipe(
      startWith(new NavigationEnd(0, '/', '/dummy/')),
      filter((event: NavigationStart) => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
    )
    .subscribe((event: NavigationStart) => {
      Object.keys(this.progressUrls).map((key, i) => {
        if (event.url === this.progressUrls[key] && event['urlAfterRedirects'] !== '/dummy/') {
          return this.isActive = true, this.index = i, this.activeClass = `active${i}`;
        }       
      });
    });
}
```

Comment: `Does anyone have any ideas on how to get the router events to fire the first time the page/component is loaded` They already do. Also don't type event as NavigationStart, It's just Event.

Comment: Thanks, I should've been clearer, there is no url property in the returned event "/", when the component first loads, do you have any pointers?

Comment: No, I can not reproduce the issue. I'm getting `url: "/"` in all of my navigation events. That's expected, the root loads with `/`, root url. Other navigation events depend on your router and what not, so I don't have enough information to say anything.

Comment: Of course, the app I'm working on is within another app, so when it's loaded; there is something within the address bar, I've found a way around the issue, but you are quite right